# Angular ng build give me an error

Tags: javascript, angular, build

I have a small app in Angular 5 and when I try to run build prod ng build --prod, I get this error:

```
Time: 4739ms
chunk {0} styles.c716146007b500deaef3.bundle.css (styles) 175 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} polyfills.997d8cc03812de50ae67.bundle.js (polyfills) 84 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} main.ee32620ecd1edff94184.bundle.js (main) 84 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js (inline) 796 bytes [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in : Can't resolve all parameters for DataService in .../src/app/services/data.service.ts: (?, [object Object]).
```

For me this is a big surprise, because in normal, default way the app it's run correctly.
I investigate other similar errors and it seems to be from dependencies.

**But the big question is, how it's possible to run ok in normal mode, and give me this error just when I run build?!**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

import { AppError } from '../common/app-error';
import { NotFoundError } from '../common/not-found-error';
import { BadInput } from '../common/bad-input';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    constructor(public url: string, private http: HttpClient) { }

    getAll() {
        return this.http
                   .get(this.url)
                   .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    create(resource) {
        return this.http
                   .post(this.url, JSON.stringify(resource))
                   .catch(this.handleError)
    }

    update(resource) {
        return  this.http
                    .patch(`${this.url}/${resource.id}`, JSON.stringify({ isRead: true}))
                    .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    delete(id) {
        return this.http
                   .delete(`${this.url}/${id}`)
                   .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: Response) {

        if(error.status === 400) {
            return Observable.throw( new BadInput(error));
        }
        if(error.status === 404) {
            return Observable.throw(new NotFoundError());
        }
        return Observable.throw(new AppError(error))

    }

}
```

And is used:

```
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class GithubFollowersService extends DataService {

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    super('https://api.github.com/users/mosh-hamedani/followers', http);
  }
}
```

.. and:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Injectable()
export class PostService extends DataService {

    // private url: string = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

    constructor(http: HttpClient) {
        super('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', http);
    }

}
```

Comment: provide code where you use the `DataService`

Comment: I added, where is used.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue might be due to the injection of `url` in your `constructor() {}`. This might provide a fix:

```
data.service.ts

import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private: router: Router, private http: HttpClient) {}
```

Wherever `this.url` is called, replace it with `this.router.url`

Comment: No, is not. I added where is used, must be a string.

Comment: The docs say that `this.router.url` should return a string: https://angular.io/api/router/Router#url. If changed in `data.service.ts`, does it not work?

Comment: No, the url must be like this: "super('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', http);"

Comment: I not url from router.

Answer (score 0):

If your angular version is 4 or greater, instead of using HttpClient, try using:

`import { Http } from '@angular/http';`

Comment: HttpClient was introduced for Angular 4 +

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem with this:

I remove @Injectable decorator from DataService

@Injectable() //remove it
export class DataService {
  ...
}

And from app.modules.ts, I also remove DataService from providers: []

providers[
  ...
  DataService //was removed
  ...
]

The constructor don't have an injectable parameter (url: string). And this was solve my problems.

**Thanks for all ideas!!!**